# jquery click on transparent div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to arrows over an image to navigate to previous or next image. The div of the arrow has no background color. When I click on the box an alert is shown. This is possible over the whole div.
When an image is shown under the div with the arrow, the click isn't working in Internet Explorer but it does work in Firefox and Chrome. The user cant navigate to the next or previous image. When you give the box with the arrow a background color, it does work but you won't be able to see the image.

Can somebody please help me? Beneath is a sample project that work immidiatly.

Thanks!

```
<div id="photoViewer">     
        <div id="photoViewerDialog" class="photoViewerWindow">
            <div id="photoViewerImageCon">
                <img src="../../Content/ShowImage.jpg" class="image" alt="photo" />
                <div id="navigationBar">
                    <div id="navigationLeft"><span><</span></div>
                    <div id="navigationRight"><span>></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="photoViewerMask"></div>    
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //transition effect     
            $('#photoViewerMask').fadeIn();
            $('#photoViewerMask').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);

            //Get the window height and width
            var winH = $(window).height();
            var winW = $(window).width();

            var borderSpace = 200;
            var minimumSize = 520;

            //Set width and height of photoviewer
            if (winW > minimumSize) {
                if ((winW - borderSpace) > minimumSize) {
                    $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow').css('width', winW - borderSpace);
                }
                else {
                    $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow').css('width', minimumSize);
                }
            }
            if (winH > minimumSize) {
                if ((winH - borderSpace) > minimumSize) {
                    $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow').css('height', winH - borderSpace);
                }
                else {
                    $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow').css('height', minimumSize);
                }
            }

            var photoViewerWindow = $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow');
            var imageCon = $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon');
            var infoCon = $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerInfoCon');
            var infoHeader = $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerInfoCon #photoViewerInfoHeader');
            var InfoThumbs = $('#photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerInfoCon #photoViewerInfoThumbs');

            //Set width and line-height of photo to show
            $(imageCon).width($(photoViewerWindow).width() - $(infoCon).width());
            $(imageCon).css('line-height', $(photoViewerWindow).height() + 'px');

            //Set the popup window to center
            $('#photoViewerDialog').css('top', winH / 2 - $('#photoViewerDialog').height() / 2);
            $('#photoViewerDialog').css('left', winW / 2 - $('#photoViewerDialog').width() / 2);

            //transition effect
            $('#photoViewerDialog').fadeIn();
        });

        $('#navigationLeft').click(function () {
            alert('left');
        });

        $('#navigationRight').click(function () {
            alert('right');
        });

    </script>
```

CSS

```
    #photoViewerMask {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9000;
    background-color:#000000;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow {
    position:fixed;
    min-width:520px;
    min-height:520px;
    max-height: 2048px;    
    z-index:9001;
    }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 2048px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9003;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: Black;
    }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon .image {
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 9003;
    }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationBar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationLeft,
   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationRight {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9910;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationLeft:hover,
   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationRight:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationLeft
   {
    /*background-color:Aqua;*/
    width: 20%;
    left: 0px;
   }
   
   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationLeft span
   {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
   }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationRight
   {
    /*background-color:Fuchsia;*/
    width: 80%;
    right: 0px;
   }

   #photoViewer .photoViewerWindow #photoViewerImageCon #navigationRight span
   {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
   }
```

Comment: It's working for me, http://jsfiddle.net/wKGpS/, are you sure you didn't append the image over the divs with arrows ?

Comment: Which version of IE is this breaking in? I created a fiddle here of your code, and it's working in IE8 and IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/z2va9/1/

Comment: For what it's worth, I've also tried IE8 in IE7 and compatibility modes, and it still works.

Comment: Hello Ricardo and Chris. Both jsfiddles look its working in the beginning but when you look closer it isn't. @RicardoLohmann: If you hover over the red cross of the image (because the image cannot be loaded) you will see that the click that will set the alert will not work. The cursor also changes back from pointer to regular cursor. So when you have a big image, you cant click anyware. I want that whole popup is clickable. Chris: Your sample looks almost working but I can only click the arrows or just around it.I want to click the whole popup.Uncomment the css of arrows background for sample

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, make a 1x1 transparent gif and use it as background-image for your div. This trick (is it?) comes from the past.

Comment: I think this will work but I don't want to use a picture. This should be able to work with only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which does not require a transparent image:
Use text which is big enough that it is not visible in your div - here's an example:

```
.my_clickable_div:after {
   content: '____________________________';
   font-size: 1000px;
   overflow: hidden;

   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Because the issue has been solved in IE9 you can put this in a conditional CSS which will be olny loaded for older IE versions, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='ie_old.css'/><![endif]-->
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a lot of z-index and that might be your issue.
Try changing your #navigationRight span and #navigationLeft span to have a superior z-index, since your 'span's might be blocking the 'click' function on that area.

This has caught me out a few times in a different situation.